# Twitter preview card not showing

Tags: twitter, social-media, twitter-card

I would like to show a preview of the twitter card I have. I've set all
meta tags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Vrienden uitnodigen">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="SayHi.Dog is een nieuw platform voor hondenouders. Leer wat het is, meld je hond aan, win prijzen en verdien beloningen voor jouw hond.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://sayhi.dog/sayhi-fb.png?v=1">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="https://sayhi.dog">
```

And I make the button share it like this:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{ urlencode($shareLink) }}
```

But I only see the url in text, no card preview when the user want's to share the url.

When I check it here https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator it's showing the card correctly but not in preview mode when the user want's to share the url.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Card previews do not show in the web sharing dialog, but they will work in the Tweet when it is posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the web sharing dialog, hit enter after you put in the URL. Then the preview should show. That worked for me.